# Intellij 2021 Cannot resolve symbol if it's from a custom maven repo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project where I'm using a dependency from a custom repository. This is what my build.gradle looks like (I have blurred out some dependencies for privacy):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'groovy'
}

group = 'com.myproject.projectx.sms'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "s3://myproject-maven-repo"
        authentication {
            awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'

    implementation 'com.myproject.top:secret-project:1.2' <------------ Gradle won't download this. why?

    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.0-groovy-3.0'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        exclude group: 'org.junit', module: 'junit'
    }

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

There are red squiggly underlines when I hover over code that's using the `top:secret-project` dependencies. This used to work in old projects, but why can't intellij recognize it in this project? Also I can run the project successfully in ubuntu terminal with `gradle bootRun`. It's just intellij cannot recognize it. It also able to recognize spring, postgres, lombok & spock dependencies.

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'com.myproject.top.secret.TopSecretService'.
```

When click on build for gradle, I keep getting this error.

```
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;)
```

I already exported the correct secret and keys in my `.bashrc` file. I also already configured `~/.aws/credentials`. But I'm still getting the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Am not really familiar with AwsImAuthentication nor the s3:// , but as it mentioned in the [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-gradle.html) that you need to add user/pass , or user/token as following

```
maven {
         url 'https://my_domain-111122223333.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/maven/my_repo/'
         credentials {
             username "aws"
             password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
         }
}
```

where CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN is enviroment variable to store your password/session .

You can also use the gradle.properties to retrive the value , just make sure to replace `System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN` with

`project.findProperty.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN` where CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN is store the password/token in your gradle properties .